# Python algorithm in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

In a list of N strings, implement an algorithm that outputs the largest n if the entire string is the same as the preceding n strings. (i.e., print out how many characters in front of all given strings match).

My code:

```
def solution(a):
    import numpy as np
    for index in range(0,a):
        if np.equal(a[index], a[index-1]) == True:
            i += 1
            return solution
        else:
            break

    return 0
 
# Test code
print(solution(['abcd', 'abce', 'abchg', 'abcfwqw', 'abcdfg'])) # 3
print(solution(['abcd', 'gbce', 'abchg', 'abcfwqw', 'abcdfg'])) # 0
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly. Have a sample desired input and output. Also, using `numpy` here might be overkill.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` ? And you are not using it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- There is no need to use `numpy` if it is only used for string comparison
- `i` is undefined when `i += 1` is about to be executed, so that will not run. There is no actual use of `i` in your code.
- `index-1` is an invalid value for a list index in the first iteration of the loop
- `solution` is your function, so `return solution` will return a function object. You need to return a number.
- The `if` condition is only comparing complete words, so there is no attempt to only compare a prefix.

A possible way to do this, is to be optimistic and assume that the first word is a prefix of all other words. Then as you detect a word where this is not the case, reduce the size of the prefix until it is again a valid prefix of that word. Continue like that until all words have been processed. If at any moment you find the prefix is reduced to an empty string, you can actually exit and return 0, as it cannot get any less than that.

Here is how you could code it:

```
def solution(words):
    prefix = words[0]  # if there was only one word, this would be the prefix
    for word in words:
        while not word.startswith(prefix):
            prefix = prefix[:-1]  # reduce the size of the prefix
            if not prefix:  # is there any sense in continuing?
                return 0  # ...: no.
    return len(prefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

The description is somewhat convoluted but it does seem that you're looking for the length of the longest common prefix.

You can get the length of the common prefix between two strings using the next() function. It can find the first index where characters differ which will correspond to the length of the common prefix:

```
def maxCommon(S):
    cp = S[0] if S else "" # first string is common prefix (cp)
    for s in S[1:]:        # go through other strings (s)
        cs = next((i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(s,cp)) if a!=b),len(cp))
        cp = cp[:cs]       # truncate to new common size (cs)
    return len(cp)         # return length of common prefix
```

output:

```
print(maxCommon(['abcd', 'abce', 'abchg', 'abcfwqw', 'abcdfg'])) # 3
print(maxCommon(['abcd', 'gbce', 'abchg', 'abcfwqw', 'abcdfg'])) # 0
```